# Calendar algorithms

Tags: python

I am doing task for my classes. I've got one where I need to show how many day of week (Mondays, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday etc.) are in specific month. For an example: March 2017 had 4 mon, 4 tue, 5 wed, 5 th, 5 fri, 4 sat, 4 sun.

So far I did...

```
class Calendar():
    def __init__(self, month, year):
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        if month < 1 or month > 12:
            print("Error 404 month not found")

    def show(self):
        print(Calendar) ##Just test

test1 = Calendar(0, 2017)

test1.show()
```

and I'm stuck, because I don't really know how can I find particular day in month using month and year.

Comment: Use the `datetime` module. Iterate through all days in the month.

Comment: It may feel like you may be cheating a bit but [`Calendar.itermonthdates()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.itermonthdates) fits the bill oh so sweet, and it's a standard library. It returns [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) for every iteration

Comment: Do you really need the day of week or just the number of days in a month? It is within the bounds of a assignment to ask for a calendar that can list the number of days in a month as there is only one month with a variable number of days and its length is 28 and 1 is added if the year is a leap year.

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks for helping but I must be honest with you. I don't really know how to use these libraries yet. Especially with OOP.

Dan, let me explain my task with more details. I have to do __init_ with 2 atribiutes year and month. Then method that will do 7 columns and shows number of days in a month. As I explained up there for March 2017 as an example:
4 4 5 5 5 4 4

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should use libraries - clearly the task is to come up with algorithm and not to use existing tools. I'm not going to write a code as this is your assignment. But I'll try to help with the approach:

1. Try defining a single known date that you know is Monday.
2. Define a single year that you know is a leap year
3. Define a months list that stores the numbers of days in each month
4. For any input month and year calculate a number of days from your know date to the first day of the month.
5. Use modulo 7 operation on the result of step 4 to find the day of the week for the first day in month
6. Now subtract the number of days in given month (but also check here for leap years) from the first ocurrence of given day of the week and use some more modulo 7 arithmetics to find out the number of particular days of the week in a given month.